# Why does Kotlin throw NullPointerException when referencing proguard-removed method?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have a method reference that is unexpectedly getting removed by Proguard. I then try to call that method from within another Kotlin class. Each time Kotlin throws a `NullPointerException`.

I've experienced this problem (probably too) many times from Java code and I always get either a `NoSuchMethodError` or `NoClassDefFoundError` and then I know to update proguard rules. The NPE is totally throwing me down the wrong debug path. Just curios why that is the exception of choice.